# Giving focus to the 'this' element in a function called by ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a span element that I want to give focus to after popping up a dialog box when the span is clicked. The span contains two glyphs, only one of which is displayed at any given moment. When the item is not checked in yet, the `unchecked` icon is displayed, and after the item is checked in, the `checked` icon is displayed.

```
<span ng-click="checkIn(this, item)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" style="display:inline"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-checked" style="display:none"></span>
<span>
```

*Some of the details have been omitted for brevity.*

The `checkIn()` function does all the work of checking in or checking out the item, displaying a dialog box, etc. I'd like to pass it the span element that was clicked, so that after all the check-in/check-out work is done, I can give focus back to it.

I've tried this:

```
function checkIn(elem, item)
{
    elem = angular.element(elem);
    ...code to display pop-ups and check item in/out...
    elem.focus();
}
```

Even though `elem` is indeed a non-null object, calling `elem.focus()` does not do appear to do anything; after the dialog div is closed (hidden), the focus returns to the top element in the browser window.

I've also tried passing the `$event` object and using `$event.target`, but with the same results.

I've also tried passing the ID of the span and accessing it with `document.getElementById()`, but still the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the `span` element to get directly passed properly to the `ng-click` handler function, so I resorted to naming it with a unique ID and passing the ID to the function.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  <td>
    <span id="chk_{{$index}}" ng-click="checkIn('chk_'+$index, item)">
      <span ...></span>
      <span ...></span>
    </span>
    ...
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

(I neglected to mention that each checkbox was part of an `ng-repeat` table element, but I'm not sure that this has anything to do with my problem.)

The `checkIn()` handler function then locates the proper element and gives it focus.

```
function checkIn(elem, item)
{
    ...code to display pop-ups and check item in/out...
    var e = document.getElementById(elem);   //elem is 'chk_nnn'
    if (e)
        e.focus();
}
```

The tricky part was passing the `$index` value correctly to the click handler function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you are probably doing it in not-optimal way, performing some DOM manipulations in controller. So you might want to check this very [good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) regarding best practices in Angular.

But regarding the actual problem. You indeed need to use `$event.target` object:

```
ng-click="checkIn($event, item)"
```

and then focus it

```
function checkIn(e, item) {
    // ...code to display pop-ups and check item in/out...
    e.target.focus();
}
```

For this make sure your spans have negative [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute, so that they can be focused programmatically:

```
<span tabindex="-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" style="display:inline"></span>
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you showed the angular way of setting focus.

Comment: @JuanMendes It would be a directive.

Comment: All DOM manipulations are done in the HTML directly using Angular (using `ng-if` and `ng-show`). Still cannot get it to set focus.

Comment: @DavidRTribble, I always use $timeout to set focus for some component... try to use $timeout...